# Error adding the invoice in QuickBooks. Invalid reference to QB customer

Tags: c#, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, qbxml, qbfc

There is an invalid reference to QuickBooks Customer "ABS, JLMN" in the Invoice. 
 QuickBooks error message: Invalid argument.  The specified record does not exist in the list.

```
<InvoiceAddRq requestID = "***">
<InvoiceAdd>
<CustomerRef>
<FullName>ABS, JLMN</FullName>
</CustomerRef>
<TxnDate>2014-10-31</TxnDate>
<TermsRef>
<FullName>*Proper existing term*</FullName>
</TermsRef>
<DueDate>2014-11-30</DueDate>
<InvoiceLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>*Proper existing term*</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<Desc>*String Value*</Desc>
<Rate>0.00</Rate>
</InvoiceLineAdd>
<InvoiceLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>*Proper existing term*</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<Desc>*Strings of text*</Desc>
<Rate>0.00</Rate>
</InvoiceLineAdd>
<InvoiceLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>*Proper existing term*</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<Desc>*Strings of text*</Desc>
<Rate>0.00</Rate>
</InvoiceLineAdd>
<InvoiceLineAdd>
<ItemRef>
<FullName>*Proper existing term*</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<Desc>*Strings of text*</Desc>
<Rate>0.00</Rate>
</InvoiceLineAdd>
</InvoiceAdd>
<IncludeRetElement>TxnID</IncludeRetElement>
<IncludeRetElement>CustomerRef</IncludeRetElement>
<IncludeRetElement>ItemRef</IncludeRetElement>
</InvoiceAddRq>
```

Please note that the values mentioned in "*"s are only place holders.
The customer ABS, JLMN is present in Quick books but still I get this error. This is not the only request while generating the request XML, there are other customers also with same properties. I am not getting any error for those customers. Can any one please let me know what can be the problem here?

Is there any chance that my company file is corrupted? I am doing many InvoiceADD and CustomerADD requests with the company file as a part of my requirements. So could that be a reason for the problem here?

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks.

Comment: Quickbook online SDK is already SDK. Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/blog/2014/09/05/final-migration-update-quickbooks-online-sdk-to-quickbooks-online-rest-api-v3
Why don't you try this usuing QBO REST V3 API ? https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
There is an invalid reference to **QuickBooks** Customer "ABS, JLMN" in the Invoice.
```

This error Occurs when Customer "ABS, JLMN"  does not exists in the **Quickbooks** and you try to add invoice against that customer.

If customer already exists in **Quickbooks** then parse the name of customer in your requestXML. Special characters also create errors.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail what you mean by parse the name of the customer in the requestXML.
Thanks

Comment: Just validate your XML with **XML Validator** available with SDK

Comment: Thank your for your response. Yes, I have validated my XML request with the xml validator but still I get the above error and also I made sure that the customer is present in the Quickbooks.
Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: Share the QWC log file and also verify Customer must be Active in the QB.